# Notify a super view when any of its sub views is set to hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an app for iOS and I have a view that contains sub views and I want to call a function when any of its sub views is set to hidden.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: How are the sub-views set to hidden?

Comment: viewToHide.hidden = YES;

Comment: Refer URL:
Someone has already answered
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033581/ios-uiview-detect-hidden-state-change-in-subview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so assuming you implement a method in the superview called `subview:(UIView *)view wasHidden:(BOOL)hidden` then you would need to call it after setting `viewToHide.hidden`:

```
viewToHide.hidden = YES;
if ([[viewToHide superview] respondsToSelector:@selector(subview:wasHidden:)]) {
    [[viewToHide superview] subview:viewToHide wasHidden:YES];
}
```

A bit crude but I believe it will work.  A better solution might be to get the superview to do the hiding itself, via (custom) methods like:

```
- (void)hideSubview:(UIView *)subview;
- (void)unhideSubview:(UIView *)subview;
```

and then it can do what it likes after (un)hiding.

Better still [might be to use KVO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033581/ios-uiview-detect-hidden-state-change-in-subview), as has been flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: thank you for your reply . 
it will work but i want to do it by observing the change in hidden property .

Comment: @poyofever. Yeah that's fair enough.  The answer you need has been linked in several places on this page.